# Init image view with frame and image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I currently have the code below to load in a user's profile picture in my iOS app. However, this is a rewrite by me to load it from an url.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 184.0f)];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placehold.it/250x250"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
    imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

The old code had this `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 100, 100)];` so that the image wouldn't be too large. How can I incorporate that into my code?

And changing `http://placehold.it/250x250` to `http://placehold.it/100x100` is not an option, since that is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 100, 100)];` ?

You can set the image later using

```
imageView.image
```

Also, you should probably take out

`imageView.layer.rasterizationScale` and `imageView.layer.shouldRasterize`,

you probably don't need them.

**on a side note**

( `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` should **NEVER** be used in such case...)

Comment: How would you rewrite it then? I don't really understand what you mean by `You can set the image later using imageView.image`.

Comment: In place of your `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];` line you can instead write `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,100,100)];` and continue the rest of your imageView customization. To "set the image later" you would simply use `imageView.image = image;`.